# How to make an Android class wait until another class completes its task?

Tags: java, android, wait, notify

I'm writing an Android messaging application, and 1 class is calling another class, and I wish for the calling class to wait for the callee class to complete before carrying on.

Caller Class (MessageManagement) code snippet is as follows:

```
private static Messenger myMessenger;

try {
  Message msg = Message.obtain();
  msg.arg1 = constructedMessage.length();
  msg.arg2 = -1;
  msg.obj = constructedMessage;
  Log.d(TAG, "Calling myMessenger.send()");
  myMessenger.send(msg);
  Log.d(TAG, "Sent");
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
// Wait here until myMessenger completes its task
doOtherStuff();
```

Right now, doOtherStuff() starts and finishes before myMessenger starts. I need myMessenger to complete before doOtherStuff() starts.

I've read about wait() and notify() but I'm not sure how to implement it here, or whether it's the right choice.

Some background about the flow of the program. It's basically a messaging app that I inherited, so I'm not exactly sure of its framework. From what I can tell tracing the flow of the code:

1. When an SMS message is received, the SMS receiver BroadcastReceiver(SmsReceiver) handles it, getting the sender address and message body, then calling a SMS handler service(HandleSmsService), which then calls the caller class in a runnable with the following code:

HandleSmsService

```
public class HandleSmsService extends Service {
  private String message;
  private MessageManagement messageManager;
  private Handler timeoutHandler = new Handler();

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, intent startid) {
    message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
    messageManager = new MessageManagement(this);
    timeoutHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 10);
  }

  private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        messageManager.handleMessage(message);
        stopSelf();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  };
```

MessageManagement is my caller class, and MessageManagement.handleMessage() is the top most code snippet presented earlier.

The MessageManagement.handleMessage() apparently calls another Handler in the callee class when it calls myMessenger.send(msg). This Handler code is as follows:

```
private Handler smsHandler = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // do some stuff
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the posted code is running on the MainThread and the reason why you are using a handler is that something asynchronous is done on another thread when receiving that message.
In that case, you can't use wait on the thread, as it will lock up the UI and probably cause an application not responding error.

Without changing too much of your code, one way to do it is to nest a listener in your constructedMessage for e.g.

```
public class DoStuffRequest {
    private OnFinishListener mOnFinishListener;
    private boolean isCanceled;
    private String mMessage;
    public interface OnFinishListener {
        public void onFinish();
    }

    public DoStuffRequest(String message) {
        mMessage = message;
    }        

    public OnFinishListener getOnFinishListener() {
        return mOnFinishListener;
    }

    public void setOnFinishListener(OnFinishListener onFinishListener) {
        mOnFinishListener = onFinishListener;
    }

    public void cancel() {
        isCanceled = true;
    }

    public void notifyFinish() {
        if (!isCanceled && mOnFinishListener != null) {
            mOnFinishListener.onFinish();
        }
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }
}
```

then use some along the line of this to get the ball rolling:

```
private static Messenger myMessenger;
private DoStuffRequest mRequest;
...

private void send(String message) {
    mRequest = new DoStuffRequest(message);    
    mRequest.setOnFinishListener(new ConstructedMessage.OnFinishListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            doOtherStuff();
        }
    });
    try {
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.arg1 = constructedMessage.length();
        msg.arg2 = -1;
        msg.obj = constructedMessage;
        Log.d(TAG, "Calling myMessenger.send()");
        myMessenger.send(msg);
        Log.d(TAG, "Sent");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void doThisIfYouWantToCancel() {
    if (mRequest != null) {
        mRequest.cancel();
    }
}
```

your Handler/Service code can now call `constructedMessage.finish()` when the async stuff is done. Depending on what doOtherStuff() does (e.g. when manipulating the UI), you might want to do this on the MainThread (the code i've written above is NOT thread safe and i assume you are calling the listener on the MainThread).
Also remember to call `constructedMessage.cancel()` in case you do not want to get notified any more (e.g. you are leaving the activity/fragment).

this is just one way to do it, depending on your needs, some other methods might be a better choice.

Comment: constructedMessage is actually just a String. I've modified my original question to provide more details of the code.

Comment: simply add a member to ConstructedMessage and getter/setter methods then. The idea behind it is to simply wrap the data you want to pass to the handler in an object with a callable listener and all the extra stuff you want to add.

Comment: i also checked your service code, i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, could you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should look something like this:

```
    try {
      Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {
                  doOtherStuff();
              }
        });
      msg.arg1 = constructedMessage.length();
      msg.arg2 = -1;
      msg.obj = constructedMessage;
      Log.d(TAG, "Calling myMessenger.send()");
      msg.sendToTarget();
      Log.d(TAG, "Sent");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The other way to do this using native means:

```
private static Messenger myMessenger = new Messenger(new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // do something what you need
        if (msg.getTarget() != null) {
            msg.sendToTarget();
        }
        return false;
    }
}));

try {
    final Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.setTarget(new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            doOtherStuff();
            return false;
        }
    }));
    msg.arg1 = constructedMessage.length();
    msg.arg2 = -1;
    msg.obj = constructedMessage;
    Log.d(TAG, "Calling myMessenger.send()");
    myMessenger.send(msg);
    Log.d(TAG, "Sent");
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your first method. Sorry for the noob question, but how do I declare/initialize the handler parameter to Message.obtain()?

Comment: I assumed you use some `Handler` to initialize your `Messenger`, and at the first method I suggest use that `Handler` to initialize `Message` instead of `Messenger`.

Comment: The handler in myMessenger exists, and there is a handleMessage() implemented in there as my updated original post indicates. However, this handler seems to be private, so I can't access it from my calling function? It seems that I'm calling a private handleMessage() from another public handleMessage(), and since the callee handleMessage() is private, the caller doesn't call it explicitly, but uses myMessenger.send(msg) instead. Not sure if I'm interpreting the code correctly.

Comment: What about second method?

Comment: Isn't that reimplementing the same handleMessage() code that resides in my callee class, into the caller class?
I tried putting the msg.sendToTarget() into the callee class, but that caused a fatal exception.

Comment: Hmmm, yes looks like it is. I can't fully imagine your app's implementation, if it's possible, could you post full classes on https://gist.github.com for example. Alternatively you can use @Su-Au Hwang's method. Just extednd ConstructedMessage from String or constract your own class with String like a member inside.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. It's quite a huge project. I've sanitized a few of the relevant files and put it on gist.github.com. Here's the link - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c03e373cc8a41acd3656

Comment: Basically, SmsReceiver receives an incoming SMS, and if it decides that it needs to handle the SMS, it calls HandleSmsService.

HandleSmsService then spawns a new Runnable, which calls MessageManagement.handleMessage().

MessageManagement.handleMessage() then sends the message via frontendMessenger.send(), and this triggers ContactManagement.handleMessage() to receive the message and perform some operations. MessageManagement is then supposed to continue only after ContactManagement.handleMessage() has completed, but right now that's not the case.

Comment: Ok, got it, but I'll check it later. I quickly looked at the code and noticed few flaws. If you explain me what do you want to do after sms was received, maybe I can help to do your code better.